# Is it possible to pass struct members In a function in c?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

For example I have the following definition of a struct in a header file;
Edit: All of this is it in C.

```
struct characterPlayer
{
    int pozPx;
    int pozPy;
};
```

And the function definition:

```
void caracterMoveDown(struct characterPlayer &player1.pozPx,struct characterPlayer &player1.pozPy);
```

And when I try to compile I get the following error:

"error: expected ',' or '...' before '.' token"

Am I doing the impossible somewhere ?
Thank you very much for the help;

I tried to initialise the player1 in the header and after that to put it in the function..no succes. I want to work with those arguments because they will be modified in the function and want to keep the new value they will get . That is why I put "&" ;

Comment: C or C++? C doesn't have references. Also, do you want to take the individual `int`s or the whole `characterPlayer` as an argument? You seem to be mixing the two.

Comment: oh yes.. but the thing is that the  problem occurs even without the references..

Comment: Is it C or C++?

Comment: Is it written in C.

Comment: Ok, then don't tag it with C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, C does not have references so you can't use `&` to take them by reference.

You can use pointers instead.

If you want to take pointers to the individual variables as arguments:

```c
void caracterMoveDown(int *pozPx, int *pozPy) {
    *pozPx = ...;
    *pozPy = ...;
}

int main(void) {
    struct characterPlayer foo;
    caracterMoveDown(&foo.pozPx, &foo.posPy);
}
```

If you want to take a pointer to the whole struct:

```c
void caracterMoveDown(struct characterPlayer *player1) {
    player1->pozPx = ...;
    player1->pozPy = ...;
}

int main(void) {
    struct characterPlayer foo;
    caracterMoveDown(&foo);
}
```